# Spring Boot @Scheduled's cron job doesn't work properly when created two jobs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

#### What I want to do

I am creating two batch processes using @Scheduled function of Spring Boot by kotlin.

1. batch to retrieve data running at 00:00 a.m. (Japan time) every day
2. batch to integrate data running at 03:00 a.m. (Japan time) every day

#### Problems

I was able to confirm from the log that the batch executed at 00:00 worked correctly, but I was unable to confirm the execution of batch 2.

### The source code in question

The following is the application code.

```
@Service
class ScheduledTaskService {

    @Scheduled(cron = "\${task.fetch-data.cron}", zone = "\${task.fetch-data.zone}")
    fun fetchData() {
        println("The time is now " + ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo")).toString())
        println("start to fetch data")
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "\${task.integrate-data.cron}", zone = "\${task.integrate-data.zone}")
    fun integrateData() {
        println("The time is now " + ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tokyo")).toString())
        println("start to integrate data")
    }
}
```

The following is the application.yml

```
task:
  fetch-data:
    cron: ${TASK_FETCH_DATA_CRON:0 0 0 * * *}
    zone: ${TASK_FETCH_DATA_ZONE:Asia/Tokyo}
  integrate-data:
    cron: ${TASK_INTEGRATE_DATA_CRON:0 0 3 * * *}
    zone: ${TASK_INTEGRATE_DATA_ZONE:Asia/Tokyo}
```

I also added `@EnableScheduling` to the main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@EnableScheduling
class APIApplication(private val apiConfig: APIConfig) : ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {
...
```

#### Things I tried

##### Verified at different times

Batch 1: 11:00 AM

Batch 2: 12:00 PM

Result: **batch 1 worked, batch 2 did not**.

##### Set the execution timing of 2 to 1 minute after 1

Batch 1: 12:20 PM

Batch 2: 12:21 PM

Result: **both 1 and 2 worked**.

##### Change the execution timing of 1 and 2 to 2->1 order

Batch 1: 14:30 PM

Batch 2: 14:05 PM

Result: **batch 2 worked, batch 1 did not**.

I am currently investigating the possibility that the results may vary depending on the time between when the server is started and when the batch is executed.

If you have any ideas, I'd love to hear them.

#### Additional information (FW/tool version, etc.)

- PC: macOS Big Sur 2.5GHz quad-core Intel Core i7 with 16GM memory
- Project SDK: Java 11 (Amazon correto)
- Spring Boot version: 2.2.4.RELEASE
- Editor: IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

Your cron looks a bit off. @Scheduled spring uses [Spring Cron](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html).

[image: Format of spring cron]

Your cron expression should be

**Midnight:** `"0 0 0 * * *"`. You can also use `@midnight` here.

**3AM:** `"0 0 3 * * *"`

Comment: Thank you for commenting!!


It was actually a mistake when I pasted my code on Stackoverflow.

The setting was like below.

```
"0 0 0 * * *"
"0 0 3 * * *"
```

I didn't know the `@midnight`. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm a newbie of Stackoverflow, so I don't know how to break lines... I'd try to find it out.

Comment: You have the Externalized property set in your application.yml. Can you just try this with simple property, i.e., task:
  fetch-data:
    cron: 0 0 0 * * *
    zone: Asia/Tokyo

Comment: remember SpEL only works for @Value bound properties. `@ConfigurationProperties` does not support SpEL expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your sincere support.
I understand that I simply define the properties as "task: fetch-data: cron: 0 0 0 * * * zone: Asia/Tokyo" in my application.yml.

Comment: I try to set the batches to start in 1 hour and 1 and a half hours respectively. 
I'll get the result back to you. I am very grateful for your interest and coaching.

Comment: No Worries. Please get back with the results. Hope we can solve your problem!

Comment: I found that both didn't work... I doubt that this problem happens since my laptop turns to sleep while I am waiting. What do you think of my idea?

Comment: yes, It will definitely not work if your laptop goes to sleep. Try to update settings so that your laptop is awake.

Comment: Understood.
Then I will set up the cron as it should be (midnight and 3 a.m.), and make the laptop always awake.
And I'll see how it goes!!
I think it'll work.

It's about 8 o'clock now, so I will check the result tomorrow morning again and reply to you!!

Comment: Hi! I am very sorry to reply such late. Everything successfully worked well since I made my PC awake!!

Comment: Awesome! Good to know!